# RESTful way to PUT multiple fields

Tags: rest

What would be the best syntax to `PUT` a multiple part message using `REST`. I have a database that requires multiple fields to submit a message.

```
First part: The quick brown fox
Second part : jumps over the
Third part ; lazy dog.
```

`PUT api.com/newdata/The quick brown fox/jumps over the/lazy dog.` perhaps? What happens if a part is empty for example

`PUT api.com/newdata/The quick brown fox//lazy dog.`

or should you just use a query string?
`PUT api.com/newdata?part1=The quick brown fox&part2=jumps over the&part3=lazy dog.`

Comment: REST is *not* RPC. The URI should be the *identifier* of the resource you update, something like `/text/12` or `/0A36FF1E` (think about it like the primary key of a record in a database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use query strings to pass new values instead put the new values into request body:

```
PUT api.com/myentities/158 

part1=The quick brown fox&part2=jumps over the&part3=lazy dog
```

or if you use json format:

```
PUT api.com/myentities/158 

{
  "part1":"The quick brown fox", 
  "part2":"jumps over the",
  "part3":"lazy dog"
}
```

*part1*, *part2*, *part3* are names of fields in *myentity*

Answer (score 0):

Submit your data as a JSON payload deserialized on the server side.